# Shouldn't Lilo be getting survivors benefits?

Tags: lilo-and-stitch

Lilo's parents died a short time ago -- I don't know if their death date is set in canon, but she does remember them and she's only 6 during the movie. In the USA, unmarried children of deceased parents are entitled to [Survivors Benefits](https://www.ssa.gov/benefits/survivors/) from the Social Security Administration until age 18 (or 19 if attending elementary or secondary school full time). Nani may be too old, but Lilo certainly isn't.

Nani and Lilo appear to be more impoverished than they should be if Lilo was getting SB every month. I'm sure this was never mentioned in the film though?

Comment: This feels like a better question for a finance-related site.  My very rough calculations suggested that a likely figure for Survivor Benefits might be $1,000 per month.  In 2002, when the film was made, it would have been somewhat lower.  In 2002, the minimum wage in Hawai'i would give a full-time worker $920 per month.  So, similar, or slightly higher than the survivor benefits.  But that's also assuming that Nani would know to apply (SSA won't come looking for you), that her parents were paying into Social Security, that they'd accrued enough points, etc.

Comment: Thanks. I wasn't so much looking for exact numbers but just thinking about the plot hole.

Comment: Feels like more of a plot hole in American society: if the US government is supposedly providing welfare benefits, why are there so many people living in poverty?

Comment: Never seen the show but if they live in Hawai’i then I wouldn’t be at all surprised if survivors benefits are not enough to live on there.